# Can't understand importing node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, web-deployment

I'm very new to web development. I'll try to make the question short. Im trying to use a javascript library called euclid.ts. Its page tells you this:

[Instructions to import euclid.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo3Nd.png)

So this i what i did:

First I ran the command. Then in my html file, called **index.html** I import a script file called sketch.js

```
<body>
<script type="module" src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then in my **sketch.js** file i have this line right at the top:

```
import {Point, Line} from '@mathigon/euclid'
```

The problem is, when I open **index.html** in the browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error solving the module “@flatten-js/core”. 
Mode specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong (and how is the browser supposed to know which file to import if I don't even specify the file in the import line)

Comment: You need a module bundler to import it like that. How are you developing your app?

Comment: @codemonkey Im trying to do a simple webpage. I have an html file, the html file references a javascript file where the code is supposed to be. The only reason I used npm is because that's what the library's website told me to (in the instructions picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for compiling/bundling is via "webpack".  https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

If you setup a folder like so:

```
/project
  package.json
  sketch.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@mathigon/euclid": "^0.6.9",
    "webpack": "^5.20.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

sketch.js

```
import { Point, Line } from '@mathigon/euclid'


console.log ("sketch")
```

and then run either `npm install` or `yarn install`

and then run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack ./sketch.js`

you can generate a bundle that includes `@mathingo/euclid` at `dist/sketch.js`

Afterwards, the script tag could look like:

```
<script src="dist/sketch.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of resolving the packages before they go into browser. Browser doesn't not know how to resolve the dependencies for the package `'@mathigon/euclid'`. Code editors on the other hand can resolve the dependencies. The error that you see would be an error for a package that `'@mathigon/euclid'` depends upon.

So the actual `sketch.js` which runs in the browser should be packaged and should be the file with code from `'@mathigon/euclid'` and all it's dependencies.

You can look at webpack-cli for an easy way to generate the bundled `sketch.js` https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cli

After installing cli i believe you could do `webpack-cli build --entry  sketch.js` (Not tested)